# Encryption in Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud-config

We use spring cloud config as configuration tool. We store passwords and other sensitive things in the config git repository. We encrypt the config using Spring `/encrypt` endpoint and put the values in config.

There is an endpoint `/env` which returns all the properties. The problem here is, the values which are encrypted returned as plain text. Is there way, we make the endpoint to return encrypted value instead of plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/env` endpoint is an actuator endpoint added by Spring Cloud Config. You should take the usual steps to secure the actuator endpoints so as not to allow unwanted access.

You can set `endpoints.configprops.keys-to-sanitize` to whatever pattern you need. The default is `password,secret,key,token,.*credentials.*,vcap_services`  Keys can be simple strings that the property ends with or regex expressions.
Refer: [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-sensitive-endpoints)

Answer (score 1):

Disable server-side decryption by setting the following property:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled: false
```

Comment: Thanks Rene!! I tried this approach. But still, `/env` endpoint of the clients return the decrypted value as plain text.